# program to add a user to MySQL

Tags: c++, sql

i have got this question to solve from one my friends.
i have searched on the net but didn't get fruitful reply.can somebody help
Write a C/C++ program to add a user to MySQL. The user should be permitted to only "SELECT" entries from the given database.

Comment: Here is a API to do that: http://mysqlcppapi.sourceforge.net/
And here is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlwrap.aspx

Comment: This is a question without any research. please try and come back if there are problems or you are stuck with something specific. I have answered this time though. Please make questions more specific and try for help when you are stuck. I suggest you study - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index.html   for mysql and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp.html for the connector documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [connector for mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/).

Then you should be executing these queries :

```
MYSQL* mysql;

// establish connection.

mysql_query(mysql, "CREATE 'username'@'serveraddress' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'");
mysql_query(mysql, "GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO 'username'@'serveraddress'");
```

The above is for select to all tables in the database. If you have some table name that you want to grant access to, then mention it instead of '*' ( database.tablename)

Comment: I suggest you to accept answers(if it works for you) for the questions you ask. Will help someone in the future and will avoid the same repetitive questions.

Comment: Please check It http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652012/connecting-visual-c-2008-to-mysql

Comment: I am doing Because stackoverflow is not allowing to ask question.

Comment: But wasn't this the answer to your question ?

Unaccepting is not good when it answers your question. Just because you are not able to link the libraries doesn't mean this is not the answer and that's just another question. get over with this question first.