# Connecting Visual c++ 2008 to MySql

Tags: mysql, visual-c++

I am trying to connect c++ to mysql.
I am using visual c++ 2008 Express Edition.

//Write a c++ Program to add a user to mysql/
//The User Should be permitted to only "select" entries from the given database

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h> 

using namespace std;

//SQL_ACTIVE_CONNECTIONS
//sql::Connection             *_con;
//sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver    *_driver;
//_driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
//_con = _driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "password");


MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL *newconn;

char USERNAME[100];                 //MYSQL username
char PASSWORD[100];                 //MYSQL password

void CreateConnection(void);        //Create Connection with mysql server.
void SelectDatabase(void);          //Create and select database.
void CreateUser(void);              //Create New user and grant Permission.
void NewConn(void);                 //Create new connection with user information
void CreateTable(void);             //Create "Product" Table to operate.
void InsertData(void);              //insert data into product table. 
void DeleteData(void);              //Delete data from product table.
void SelectData(void);              //Retrieve data From product table;


int main()
{
    char ch;
    int select;
    char uname[100],pass[100];
    CreateConnection();
    SelectDatabase();
    cout<<"\n\nEnter your login infomation\nTo delete and retrieve use ADMIN account\n";
    cout<<"If you are new user your account will be create with insert privilege.\n";
    cout<<"UserName :";                                     
    gets(uname);
    mysql_escape_string(USERNAME,uname,strlen(uname));      //Assign username in USERNAME variable.
    cout<<"Password :";
    gets(pass);
    mysql_escape_string(PASSWORD,pass,strlen(pass));        //Assign password in PASSWORD variable
    CreateUser();
    NewConn();
    cout<<"\nSelect option.";
    do
    {
        cout<<"\n1. INSERT\n2. DELETE\n3. RETRIEVE\n";
        cin>>select;
        switch(select)
        {
        case 1:
            InsertData();
            break;
        case 2:
            DeleteData();
            break;
        case 3:
            SelectData();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Wrong selection \n");
            break;
        }
        cout<<"Do You want to continue.....(Y/N)\n";
    }while(('Y'==getchar())||('y'==getchar()));
    mysql_close(newconn);
    return 0;
}


//Create connection with mysql server with username and password NULL.
void CreateConnection()
{
    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (conn == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Error : %s\n"<<mysql_error(conn);
        exit(1);
    }
    if(mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", NULL,NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Error : %s\n", mysql_error(conn);
        exit(1);
    }
}


//select the database, if it is not present then create .
void SelectDatabase()
{

    if(mysql_query(conn, "create database user"))   //Query for creat3 database USER
    {
        if(mysql_errno(conn)==1007)                 //Error number 1007 means database already Exist
        {
            if(mysql_select_db(conn,"user"))        //Query for Selecte database USER
            {
                cout<<"Error :",mysql_error(conn);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Error :",mysql_error(conn);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else                                            //This else part will be executed only if database is create without error                                  
    {
        if(mysql_select_db(conn,"user"))            //Query for Selecte database USER
        {
            cout<<"Error :",mysql_error(conn);
            exit(1);
        }
        CreateTable();                              //creating tables in USER database
    }   
}

//Create account for new user and grant permission
void CreateUser()
{
    char cmd[200];  
        sprintf(cmd,"create user '%s'@'localhost' identified by '%s'",USERNAME,PASSWORD); //prepare query to create user with USERNAME and PASSWORD.
        if(mysql_query(conn,cmd))
        {
            if(mysql_errno(conn)==1396)     //Error number 1396 means that user already exists
            {
                cout<<"WELCOME %s\n"<<USERNAME;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<mysql_error(conn);
                exit(1);
            }
        }
        else
        {       
            sprintf(cmd,"grant insert on user.* to '%s'@'localhost'",USERNAME); //grant permission for created user.
            if(mysql_query(conn,cmd))
            {
                cout<<mysql_error(conn);
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Your Account created %S\n"<<USERNAME;
            }
        }
        mysql_close(conn);
}

//create sample table PRODUCT with two coloumn 1.P_ID and 2.P_Name
void CreateTable()
{
    if(mysql_query(conn,"CREATE TABLE product (P_Id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,P_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (P_Id));"))
    {
        cout<<"Error :%s"<<mysql_error(conn);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Table created\n";
    }
}

//create connection with USERNAME and PASSWORD supplied by user. 
void NewConn()
{

    newconn = mysql_init(NULL);

  if (newconn == NULL) {
      cout<<"Error : %s\n"<< mysql_error(newconn);
      exit(1);
  }

  if (mysql_real_connect(newconn, "localhost", USERNAME,PASSWORD,"user", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL) {
      cout<<"Error : %s\n"<< mysql_error(newconn);
      exit(1);
  }
}

//insert data into Product table.
void InsertData()
{

    char cmd[200];
    char pname[100],PNAME[100];
    cout<<"Enter Product Name :";  //product name that would be added in PRODUCT details
    cin>>pname;
    mysql_escape_string(PNAME,pname,strlen(pname));
    cout<<cmd<<"insert into Product (P_NAME) values('%s')"<<pname);

    if(mysql_query(newconn,cmd))
    {
        cout<<"Error :%s"<<mysql_error(newconn);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"product added\n";
    }
}

//Delete data  from product table, it require ADMIN privilege.
void DeleteData()
{
    char cmd[200];
    char pname[100],PNAME[100];
    cout<<"Enter Product Name :";           //Enter product name to delete the details
    cout<<pname;
    mysql_escape_string(PNAME,pname,strlen(pname));
    sprintf(cmd,"delete from Product where P_Name='%s'",pname);//prepare delete query.
    if(mysql_query(newconn,cmd))
    {
        cout<<"Error :%s",mysql_error(newconn);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"product deleted\n";
    }
}

//Retrieve data from Product table, it require ADMIN privilege.
void SelectData()
{
    char cmd[200];
    char pname[100],PNAME[100];
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    int num_fields,i;
    cout<<"Enter Product Name :"; //Enter product name to see the details
    cin>>pname;
    mysql_escape_string(PNAME,pname,strlen(pname));
    cout<<cmd<<"Select * from Product where P_Name='%s'"<<pname); //prepare select statement
    if(mysql_query(newconn,cmd))
    {
        cout<<"Error :%s"<<mysql_error(newconn);
    }
    else
    {
        result = mysql_store_result(conn);
        num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
        cout<<"\nPRODUCT ID\tPRODUCT NAME\n";
        cout<<"----------------------------------\n";
        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
        {
            for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
            {
                printf("%s\t\t ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL"); //display product information
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        mysql_free_result(result);
    }
}
```

But the Compiler Is not able to link With MySql Project.

I think I need to Link throgh Project->properties something Libraries.
I had installed mysql-connector-c++-1.0.5-win32 from [http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=369369] website.

Still it is not able to detect my files.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html

Please read the link and add the references properly. I suggest you read the documentation atleast once since you want to use it.

Comment: I have Visual c++ 2008 and Installed mysql-connector-c++-1.0.5-win32 from [http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=369369] and installed in this location C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C++ 1.0.5 .Now But i need to do more to run my program.Please tell step bye step process.

Comment: okay . add the references properly. Did you read the documentation - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html


Please read the documentation and add the references properly.

Comment: And close the other question because that answer is done for that question. This is just another question and not good to do these things like this.

Comment: The link I have posted gives you step by step. Please read documentation before you ask questions. Let the question be specific always. You would lose this account too if you are not accepting answers properly.

Comment: Ok.Reading Documentation.then if problem occur i will ask you.

Comment: i have Read the Full Documentation still its Not able to find Connection.Error Are "1>------ Build started: Project: test3, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>test3.cpp
1>.\test3.cpp(24) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>.\test3.cpp(24) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int a
1>.\test3.cpp(124) : error C3861: 'mysql_select_db': identifier not found
1>.\test3.cpp(126) : error C3861: 'mysql_error': identifier not

Comment: Have a look at the examples in that documentation mate. please take a look.

Comment: You have have mysql++ and not conforming to the standards of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html. Refer this example and change it. Since you have installed this connector. But if u want to still use what u have written, then the library for that is http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/.

Please refer to the example and change ur program

Comment: i am compiling their program after adding reference.Error coming " fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libmysql.lib".one more thing i am not able to understand the instruction which is given in link suggested by you [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html].I am not able to understand this.Please see comment under below this one.

Comment: Under Linker, Input, add mysqlcppconn.lib into the Additional Dependencies text field.The application needs to access the MySQL Connector/C++ Dynamic Linked Library at run time. Therefore, mysqlcppconn.dll must be in the same directory as the application executable, or somewhere on the system's path.

    Copy mysqlcppconn.dll to the same directory as the application. Alternatively, extend the PATH environment variable using SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\cpp. Alternatively, you can copy mysqlcppconn.dll to the Windows installation Directory, typically c:\windows.

Comment: "mysqlcppconn.dll must be in the same directory as the application executable"-What does that mean.I have copied mysqlcppconn.dll to my project file.still the same problem.

Comment: to your debug directory. the place where the exe is. it may be debug or release according to your build configuration. Please check where your projectname.exe is , in your project.

Comment: Did you really check that example. what is that you are not able to understand. see how to add references in Visual studio.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Goto this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html and use the same program and modify according to your needs. You just asked for some connector for mysql to c++ in your previous question and now using code which is using a different mysql++ api. You have to conform to one standard here.

Comment: error coming "fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mysqlcppconn.lib'".. The Thing is that Myserver doesnnot contain anything called 'mysqlcppconn.lib'.

Comment: Even through I have installed C++ connecor and copying 'mysqlcppconn.lib' to c:\winodws libary and writing the'mysqlcppconn.lib' by following this"Under Linker, Input, add mysqlcppconn.lib into the Additional Dependencies text field. " it not able to detect.can you tell me how to add in system path.The PATH environment variable using SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\cpp".-Does it mean i need to give the path where my program.cpp file is being located.If yes. by writing this how 'mysqlcppconn.lib' can be dectected.

Comment: just that library in your debug directory. its always detected by this. dont copy elsewhere. I dont think copying it to windows directory and all other things matter.give the directory of lib also in the library's directories of linker and add the name in input. Now it may work.

Comment: by the way, how did you link it. Static or dynamic.   If you have doubts, do these steps -http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html and stop when you see those last steps about dynamic linking. You should not do them. Its either static or dynamic.


considering you are confident about doing these correctly. Keep the mysqlcppconnlib in your debug directory and add its path to your library path and then add mysqlcppconnlib to input - both in linker options which you must be knowing how to do by now.